# Submit after a jquery-ajax function

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I check two values with ajax. And if both are correct then i want to make a submit (post-back).
But the post-back doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
 $('form').submit(function () {

            var correctCaptcha = false;
            var correctWebcode = false;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Competition/CheckForm',
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == true) {
                    $('#recaptcha_response_field').removeClass("captchaError");
                    correctCaptcha = true;
                }
                else {
                    Recaptcha.reload();
                    $('#recaptcha_response_field').addClass("captchaError");
                }
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
             // like the code above (for webcode)
        });

        if (correctCaptcha == true && correctWebcode == true) {
            document.forms['form'].submit();
        }
        else { return false; }
    });
```

Comment: At what point does it fail? Can you confirm that `correctCaptcha` and `correctWebcode` are both `true`?

Comment: yes it works now...it was the async:false that i missed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Async:false`

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Competition/CheckForm',
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                $('#recaptcha_response_field').removeClass("captchaError");
                correctCaptcha = true;
            }
            else {
                Recaptcha.reload();
                $('#recaptcha_response_field').addClass("captchaError");
            }
        }
    });
```

This will cause the infinite loop:

```
if (correctCaptcha == true && correctWebcode == true) {
    document.forms['form'].submit();
}
```

So use use like this here

```
if (correctCaptcha == true && correctWebcode == true) {
    return true;
}
else {return false;}
```

Comment: +1. That would solve it, But it's better (if possible) to do it in all in one AJAX request, then using async:false

Comment: I would suggest not to go with setting `async` to `false` because it stops the browser completely until you get the response. Sometimes it even hangs the browser if the connection is slow. If there are other ways to solve the problem this is not the adviceable one.

Answer (score 2):

Since `ajax` is async in nature you cannot expect those variables to be set right away when ajax call. You can either set `async` to false or submit the form inside success handler. Try this.

```
$('form').submit(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Competition/CheckForm',
                type: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == true) {
                        $('#recaptcha_response_field').removeClass("captchaError");
                        $('form')
                        .unbind('submit')//we dont need any handler to execute now
                        .submit();
                    }
                    else {
                        Recaptcha.reload();
                        $('#recaptcha_response_field').addClass("captchaError");
                    }
                }
            });


            $.ajax({
                 // like the code above
            });


            return false;//To prevent the form from being submitted.
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `$.ajax` works asynchronously, your way won't submit the form, you should submit the form in the callback function.